# With a half-wave rectifier, wouldn't the charges accumulated on one side?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electronics, electrical-engineering

In a normal alternating current circuit, the charges just travel back and forth, so they won't accumulate. However, if only half wave can pass through, then will the charges get accumulated on one end of the circuit? Will it cause any problem with the generator?

Answer (score 0):

An ideal diode has infinite resistance in the "reverse" direction. When the voltage is in the forward direction charge passes through the diode and the same amount of charge returns to the generator throughother parts of the circuit. When the voltage is in the reverse direction no current can flow in the circuit through the diode. This instantly stops the current all the way around the circuit, and so there is no build-up of charge at the diode.